# Grails: how to get a controller by controllerName in a filter?

Tags: grails, filter

I have a filter and the `controllerName` var getting controller target.

For example:
when user try to access `/myApp/book/index`, my filter is triggered and `controllerName` is equals `book`. How can I get a BookController instance?

Tks

---

**EDIT:**

I can get an `Artefact` using:

```
grailsApplication.getArtefactByLogicalPropertyName("Controller", "book")
```

But what I do with this artefact?

Comment: Why do you want a controller instance? Sounds like a design flaw.

Comment: I need to call an action from my Filter and then redirect to a external application (preparing my app to receive future requests). In other words, I need to update my model, before redirect.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The controller will be registered as a spring bean.  Just grab it by name:

```
applicationContext.getBean('mypackage.BookController') // or
def artefact = grailsApplication.getArtefactByLogicalPropertyName("Controller", "book")
applicationContext.getBean(artefact.clazz.name)
```

Answer (score 5):

As Burt said, you probably don't want one controller instance inside your filter. This is a wrong way to solve your problem.

Grails Controllers as injected automagically by Spring Framework, and there is some black magic and procedures made when creating it. So, I can assure you this is not the way to solve this problem.

As you yourself described, you want to call your action, and I can imagine you're trying to reuse some code that resides in your action, maybe to generate some data in your database, or even to work with your HTTP session, am I right?

So, you can do two things to solve this kind of issue.

1) Just redirect your request flow to to your controller/action like this:

```
if (something) {
  redirect controller: 'xpto', action: 'desired'
  return false
}
```

2) Or you can get the logic inside your action (that is doing that dirty job you want to run), separate that logic inside one service, and reuse the service in both classes (action / service) this way:

**MyService.groovy**

```
class MyService { 
  def methodToReuse() {
    (...)
  }
}
```

**MyController.groovy**

```
class MyController {

  def myService //auto-injected by the green elf

  def myAction = {
    myService.methodToReuse()
  }
}
```

**MyFilters.groovy**

```
class MyFilters {

  def myService //auto-injected by the red elf

  (...)
  myService.methodToReuse()
  (...)

}
```

[]s,

Comment: @lucastex, tks for your explanation. I'm in a timeless project, so I need the fastest way to to this - you know what I'm talking about :). But in next release I'll follow your tip and use a Service to reuse code.

Comment: What would be faster than copying the action code to a new file and using this file in both points? If you "instantiate" a new controller, you could experience some other strange issues, since it is all managed by the framework.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to call `newInstance` on the artefact you've retrieved.  `newInstance` works just like the constructor so you can provide any parameters you would to a normal constructor call.

So you can probably just do:

```
def bookController = grailsApplication.getArtefactByLogicalPropertyName("Controller", "book").newInstance()
```

Answer (score 2):

Working code:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.ServletContextHolder
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.GrailsApplicationAttributes
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext

ApplicationContext applicationContext = (ApplicationContext) ServletContextHolder.getServletContext().getAttribute(GrailsApplicationAttributes.APPLICATION_CONTEXT)
def grailsApplication

String nameController = "search"
def artefact = grailsApplication.getArtefactByLogicalPropertyName("Controller", nameController)
def controller = applicationContext.getBean(artefact.clazz.name)
```